# confirmDialog with data from SelectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I want to show the data selected previously (from p:selectOneMenu) by user before to submit.

i use "p:SelectOneMenu", when i click Submit i have the values in the "@Postconstruct method".

```
<h:form>
<h:panelGrid id="grid" columns="2">
 <p:selectOneMenu id="atmo" value="#{selectOneMenuView.ac_mo}" 
                    required="true" style="width:125px">
                    <p:ajax listener="#{selectOneMenuView.verif_acmo}"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="nothing" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="Yes" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="No" />
</p:selectOneMenu>

<p:selectOneMenu id="nb" value="#{selectOneMenuView.bless}" converter="nbConverter" 
                panelStyle="width:80%" effect="fade" required="true" 
                var="b" style="width:720px" filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Bless ..." itemValue="#{null}" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{selectOneMenuView.blessures}" var="bless"
                                itemLabel="#{bless.code_nb} || #{bless.libelle_nb}" itemValue="#{bless}"/>
    <p:column style="width:10%">
            <h:outputText value="#{b.code_nb}" />
        </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{b.libelle_nb}" />
    </p:column>
</p:selectOneMenu>
</h:panelGrid>

<p:commandButton value="Submit" actionListener="#{selectOneMenuView.btn}" update="grid growl"   
                    style="margin-left:25px" icon="ui-icon-check" oncomplete="PF('confirmDlg').show()">
        <p:confirm header="Confirmation" message="Are you sure ?" icon="ui-icon-alert" />
    </p:commandButton>
<p:confirmDialog global="true"  showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" widgetVar="confirmDlg" >
    <p:outputLabel value="value N1 : #{selectOneMenuView.ac_mo}"/>
     <p:outputLabel value="value N2 : #{selectOneMenuView.bless.libelle_nb}"/>
    <p:commandButton value="Confirm" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
    <p:commandButton value="Cancel" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
</p:confirmDialog>
</p:panel>
</h:form>
```

i'm working with "@RequestScoped" from "javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped" in my managedbean.

NB : after validation (submit) i have the right values. so setters and getters works perfectly

NB 2 : same problem with "@ViewScoped" and "@SessionScoped"

this is the code of managedbean

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class SelectOneMenuView {

// ---- begin : ac mo
private String ac_mo;
// Getter and Setter of ac_mo
// ---- end : ac mo

// ----- Begin Blessure
private Nb bless;
private List<Nb> blessures;
@ManagedProperty("#{blessureBean}")
private NbBean nbbean;
// getters and setters of Blessure's elements
// ----- end Blessure

// ------ begin : postconstruct 
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    blessures = nbbean.getBlessures();
    this.ac_mo = "nothing";
}
// ------ end of postconstruct

public void btn()
{
    // some stuff
    }
 }
```

Comment: you write about a selectonemenu that needs to update things, but you do not show that code... Please create an [mcve]

Comment: If you have RequestScoped, after the ajax call of the submit p:commandButton  the managed bean will be recreated. Looks like you need ViewScope to have the data in the dialog.

Comment: same issue with View and Session scope

Comment: Solutions are added in an answer, not by editing the question...

Comment: Hmmm cannot change my vote to a duplicate, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10031159/how-to-rerender-part-of-page-with-form-in-jsf-2-0 is one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved with this :

```
 <p:selectOneMenu> 
  ... do something ... 
  <p:ajax event="change" update="confirmdialog" /> 
 </p:selectonemenu>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

How will that work with a request scoped bean? Please change your bean to view scoped so that the data is retained between requests.

Comment: i think there is only one request in my case.
I try with "@ViewScoped" and "@SessionScoped", same issue

Comment: What does not make sense to me is, you see values in the post construct. How can that be? Post-construct is applied before the bean is put in scope so if somehow post construct is being invoked, that means your bean is being reconstructed. you need to post the bean code as well. In other values, you lost what was posted...

Comment: i updated the post with the code of managedBean. In the PostConstuct i initialize the value of "ac_mo" with : nothing. So when i click Submit, in the dialog i have "nothing" and not the chosen value.

Comment: value="#{selectOneMenuView.ac_mo}"  is that supposed to be ac_mortel. If so, for any ajax call you have to update the proper dialog (portion of web page), in your case <p:confirmDialog id="confirmDialogId ..> and <p:selectOneMenu update="confirmDialogId"

Comment: i try your suggestion, before i click "Confirm" (on the confirmDialog) same values (in the PostConstruct), but after clicking "Confirm" i have a new confirmDialog with the right values.

Comment: sadly no, because i want to show the right values before the confirmation.

Comment: your suggestion of updating the confirmDialog was good, but i it's work with a new ajax event not directly in selectOneMenu. <p:selectOneMenu> ... do something ... <p:ajax event="change" update="confirmdialog"  /> </p:selectonemenu>